# How to connect a 23LC1024 to a breadboard?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, ram

I just got my [23LC1024-E/ST](https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/268/20005142C-1512963.pdf) module, and I realized how tiny it is. How do people work with this? It's obviously not breadboard friendly. Are there RAM modules out there for Arduinos/ESP8266s that are more to scale than this one?

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=smd+adapter&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: The datasheet indicates that that part should be available in a PDIP package,which would fit a breadboard.

Comment: @PeterBennett, thanks !